# Pattern to parsing datetime with daylight savings time using Joda time

Tags: time, jodatime, dst

How to use joda time to parse a date time value like this "2011-03-01T01:00:00-07:00"
Does anyone has any code sample to parse the above datetime pattern?

Answer (score 1):

This is an ISO formatted date string. Jodatime supports it as follows:

```
DateTimeFormatter psr = ISODateTimeFormat.dateTimeParser()

DateTime date = psr.parseDateTime("2011-03-01T01:00:00-07:00")
```